# Let $T$ be $S$ are bounded linear operators, why are $\|Tx-Sx\| \le \|T-S\| \|x\|$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be $S$ are bounded linear operators, why are $\|Tx-Sx\| \le \|T-S\| \|x\|$?
Can anyone please explain this result?

Comment: Notice this conspicuous typographical difference: $||T-S|| ||x||$ versus $\|T-S\| \|x\|$. Or $||a|| ||b||$ versus $\|a\|\|b\|$.  The latter is standard and I changed it.  It's coded as \|T-S\| \|x\| $\qquad$

Answer (score 6):

Since  :$$\|T-S\|=\sup_{\|x\|\neq 0}\frac{\|Tx-Sx\|}{\|x\|}$$
then we have
$$\frac{\|Tx-Sx\|}{\|x\|}\le \|T-S\|$$
for every $x\in E$ (with $\|x\|\neq 0$)
therefore $\|Tx-Sx\|\le \|T-S\|\cdot||x||$

Comment: I made  mistake wait

Comment: @user1952009, Ok

Answer (score 2):

$Tx-Sx = (T-S) x$, and $T-S$ is a bounded linear operator (since its norm is at most $\lVert T\rVert + \lVert S \rVert$.

Then, the result follows by the definition of bounded operator on $T-S$.

Comment: What property of bdd linear operator are you referring to?

Comment: A bdd linear operator $A$ is one that $\lVert A x \rVert \leq \lVert A \rVert \quad \lVert x \rVert$.

Comment: Okay then which property are you refering to for Tx - Sx =(T-S)x?

Comment: Its just the fact that bounded linear operators form a vector space and the definition of addition on that vector space.

Comment: Okay can you refer to the property?

Comment: Definition of a vector space?